# Oracle - Access a remote file to read

Tags: oracle

I have this very specific requirement.

My database server is running on some linux server X, where I have written some stored procedure which will read the file from a DIRECTORY and create an XML table based on the content of that xml file.

Now, The file in picture can come from any machine i.e. it is uploaded by user in Browser and then we need to process it with the stored procedure.

Is there a way I can access the file of my local machine from the database server without mount/ftp? I mean, is there any utility in Oracle which can access file system of the client to read the file content?

Comment: I am confused.  You say that the file is uploaded by a user in a browser.  If so, the application that allows this upload would, presumably, be writing the file somewhere on the database server (presumably, a `blob` column in some table).  If that's the case, it's easy enough to write a stored procedure that reads the file.  But then you talk about accessing a file stored anywhere presumably without a user uploading it which doesn't make sense.  If a database could access any file on any machine, then my Oracle database could reach out and steal information from your laptop whenever I wanted.

Comment: I got the answer, I am storing the file on my local machine and wanted to access it from the server. Currently, I am not writing to a BLOB column in database, which I will do now to address my problem.

Answer (score 1):

> is there any utility in Oracle which can access file system of the client to read the file content?

No, there is not. PLSQL program cannot reach your client PC. You have to upload it to the server then can use `UTL_FILE` to interpret it.